# how to capture all commands being done from exe in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, decryption

I have an exe file that making some commands on cmd and powershell

I want to know this commands

I have tried this notepad (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath

but it gave me my commands not the commands that the app did

Comment: "I have an exe file that making some commands on cmd and powershell" - How can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

Most such programs do not provide interactive input to cmd/PS – instead they provide the shell command as part of cmd.exe's "command line", e.g. they run `powershell.exe -Command {Do-Something}`. So you should be able to use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace all "process/thread" events; they will have the command line of every new process.